# SQL Server and multiline text form MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Table for news in my database. One column (message) should accept multiline text from my website.

When I add text, for example:

"test

test"

MVC formats it to test\r\n\r\ntest"  which is understandable for me, but why SQL Server saves it as "testest"? How can I fix it? I use nvarchar(MAX) for message column, which i changed from text, text doesnt work for me too.

message field options are defaults, except allow nulls which I changed to "NO".

Comment: can you please include database field value into you question ? what data stored in database for this column ?

Comment: may be you are sending data to sql server as text you should send it as html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you have to do anything to have new lines saved in DB. Text would appear like that because management studio display everything in a single line. Try to retrieve the data into a TextArea on your page and see if the newlines are preserved. They should.

If you are displaying this on the page (not in a TextArea), those newlines won't be preserved because HTML does not understand `\r\n`

Comment: Ok, I think I'll solve this problem. I thought that SQL doesnt know where should be new lines, but it knows. Just didnt visualize it for me:)